# xml to array - remove empty array php

Tags: php, xml

I have an xml data and i need to convert this xml into an array ,i use the bellow PHP code,

```
$xml                       = new SimpleXMLElement($data); // $data contain the xml data
$transaction_result        = json_decode(json_encode($xml),true);
```

This is working ,but the problem is.

If a node in xml is empty,That value automatically converted as an empty array.Is it possible to remove the empty array?

**Example:**
if the node in xml is `<name></name>` then the result become

```
array('name'=>array());
```

My expected result is

```
array('name'=>'');
```

How is it possible to overcome this issue?

Comment: You can try passing some options to SimpleXMLElement to filter out empty nodes, for example `LIBXML_NOBLANKS` see: http://php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php

Comment: I tried new SimpleXMLElement($data,LIBXML_NOBLANKS) ,but getting the same result